# angular rest service not returning value in first call

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have 3 component 
1. LeftMenuComponent
2. AppComponent
3. SummeryComponent

Also, I have two service one for rest call and another for share data to the component. (RestService, ComponentService)

On selection, the list from LeftMenuComponent I am calling loadService() function and from there I am calling emit contains function from the service summeryComponent. which subscribe the restservice to pull the data and emit it.

All working fine but I have to click twice. i need data to be cahange and reflect in summerycomponent in one click.

I try to use rxjs/Subscription also but same result.

Left-memu-component.html

```
<mat-list-item><a routerLink="/summery" (click)="loadService($event, subitem.CATID, subitem.ID)">{{subitem.NAME}}</a></mat-list-item>
```

Left-Menu-Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from '../rest.service';
import { Category } from '../models/category.model';
import { ArrayType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
import { ComponentService } from '../component.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-left-menu',
  templateUrl: './left-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-menu.component.css']
})

export class LeftMenuComponent implements OnInit {
 showFiller = false;
  constructor(private restService:RestService,private componentService:ComponentService) { }
  localdata:Category[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restService.getAllDepartment().subscribe(data=> this.localdata = data );
  }

  loadService(event,CATID,SUBID?){
    console.log(CATID);
    console.log(SUBID);
    this.componentService.getSummery(CATID,SUBID);
  }


}
```

summery-component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid example-sidenav-content">
  <div>
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let item of summery">

        <mat-card class="example-card">
          <mat-card-header>
            <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
            <mat-card-title>{{item.TITLE}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{item.SUBTITLE}}</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card-header>
          <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
          <mat-card-content>
            <p>
              {{item.CONTENT}}
            </p>
          </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
            <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
          </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Summery-Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from '../rest.service';
import { Summery } from '../models/summery.model';
import { ComponentService } from '../component.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summery',
  templateUrl: './summery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summery.component.css']
})
export class SummeryComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private restService:RestService,private componentService:ComponentService) { }
  summery:Summery[];
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.summery==null)
    {
      this.restService.getSummery().subscribe(data=>this.summery=data);
    }
    this.componentService.change.subscribe(change=>
    {
      this.summery = change;
    }
    );



  }

}
```

component-service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Summery } from './models/summery.model'
import { RestService } from './rest.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentService {

  summery : Summery[]=null;


  constructor(private restService:RestService) { 
    this.summery = null;
    console.log(this.summery);
  }


@Output() change:EventEmitter<Summery[]> = new EventEmitter();

  setSummery(CATID,SUBID?){
    this.restService.getSummery(CATID,SUBID).subscribe(data=>this.summery=data);
    console.log("chekc");
  }
   getSummery(CATID,SUBID?){
     this.restService.getSummery(CATID,SUBID).subscribe(data=>this.summery=data);
    this.change.emit(this.summery);
    console.log("chekc");
    return this.summery;
  }

}
```

rest-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { first } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/first';
import { Category} from './models/category.model';
import { error } from 'util';
import { Summery } from './models/summery.model';
import { Summary } from '@angular/compiler';
// import { Category } from 'src/app/models/category.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RestService {
  public _url: string = "http://localhost:52343/api/";


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getAcess(username:string, password:string): Observable<any>{

    let main_url = this._url + "User";
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params= params.append('username', username);
    params= params.append('password', password);
    console.log(main_url);
    return this.http.get(main_url,{ params: params });
  }

  getAllDepartment():Observable<Category[]>{

    let main_url = this._url + "getProjectList";
    console.log(main_url);

     return this.http.get(main_url).pipe(map((data:Category[])=> data.map((item:Category) => new Category(item.ID, item.Name,item.SubDetail))));

  }

  getSummery(cid? :number,sid? :number):Observable<Summery[]>{
    let main_url = this._url +  "getSummery";
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if(cid !=null){
      params= params.append('cid', cid.toString());
    }
    if(sid !=null){
      params= params.append('sid', sid.toString());
    }
    console.log(main_url);
    // return this.http.get(main_url,{ params: params }).pipe(map((data:Summery[])=> data.map((item:Summery)=> new Summery(
    //   item.ID,
    //   item.SUBID,
    //   item.CATID,
    //   item.HEADER,
    //   item.TITLE,
    //   item.SUBTITLE,
    //   item.MEDIA,
    //   item.CONTENT
    // ))));
    return this.http.get(main_url,{ params: params });

  }
}
```

NO ERROR ONLY NOT WORKING IN ONE CLICK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscribe method call in your observable is asynchronous so its normal to have this kind of behavior ,in order to make it work yu should emit your value inside the callback function when yout subscribing like follow :

```
this.restService.getSummery(CATID,SUBID).subscribe(data => this.change.emit(data));
```

but in preference yu should subscribe to your observale in your component rather than the service itself without the need to use a subject or event emitter.